# Why does "if (char a = f())" compile whereas "if ((char a = f()))" does not?

Tags: c++, c++14

```
#include <iostream>

char f()
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    // Compiles
    if (char a = f())
        std::cout << a;
        
    // Does not compile (causes a compilation error)
    // if ((char a = f()))
    //     std::cout << a;

    return 0;
}
```

One can declare a local variable and assign a value to it inside an `if` statement as such:

```
if (char a = f())
```

However, adding an additional pair of parentheses, leading to `if ((char a = f()))`, causes the following compilation error:

> error: expected primary-expression before ‘char’

Why is that? What is the difference between both? Why is the additional pair of parentheses not just considered redundant?

Comment: However, `char a; if ((a = f()))` will compile. :)

Comment: Different scope on `a` though.

Comment: To have the same scope, and a parenthesized expression, try either `if (char a = (f()))` or `if (char a; (a = f()))`

Comment: @BenVoigt My intent was to be able to do something like `if ( !(char a = f()) )`, which your second suggestion allows (`if ( char a; !(a = f()) )`), but it is not available in C++14.

Comment: @Ramanewbie: That particular code can be handled by swapping the controlled-block of `if` with the controlled-block of `else`, instead of using `!`.  In particular, accessing `a` within the controlled-block of `if (!a)` is pretty useless.... `a` must be zero or you wouldn't enter the `if` at all.

Comment: @BenVoigt
"accessing `a` within the controlled-block of `if (!a)` is pretty useless"
> Yes. I should have said instead that my intent was to do something like `if ( (char a = f()) > 0 )`. Then it could have been useful to access `a` within the controlled-block.

"That particular code can be handled by swapping the controlled-block of `if` with the controlled-block of `else`"
> That only stands if there is an `else`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put it simply, C++ syntax allows the *condition* inside an [`if` statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) to be either an *expression* or a [*declaration*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations).

So, `char a = f()` is a declaration (of the variable named `a`).

But `(char a = f())` is not a declaration (and is also not an expression convertible to `bool`).